# Pass index into FormArray Control validator

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `FormArray` with simple inputs. I want to pass validator function (custom) an index of the input in `FormArray`, since my validator is based on that. For example, I want each subsequent `AbstractControl` to have more letters than the one before (this is only just an example, passing an index is what I really need to achieve).

I mean if I can get something like this

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this.items?.length ? this.items : this.getDefaults(this.size)

    const inputs: FormArray = this.formGroup.get('inputs') as FormArray
        for (let item of this.items) {
            inputs.push(this.fb.control(
            item.value,
            this.validator(),
            this.asyncValidator(),
            ))
        }
}

private validator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (abstractControl: AbstractControl/*, indexInArray */) => {
        // const lenOfPrev = this.items[indexInArray - 1].value.length
        if (abstractControl.value.length <= 0 /* lenOfPrev */) {
            return {
                notLargeEnough: 'should be bigger'
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your current code

Comment: @KurtHamilton here you go. Commented parts are the parts I want to work

Answer (score 1):

Your aim is to validate a control against another control. The fact that they are in a form array is slightly irrelevant.

When writing a custom validator, you are bound by its [interface](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn):

```js
interface ValidatorFn {
  (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null
}
```

So if you can't inject a reference to another control into the interface function, your only other option is to inject the other control into the function itself.

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this.items?.length ? this.items : this.getDefaults(this.size)

    const inputs: FormArray = this.formGroup.get('inputs') as FormArray
    this.items.forEach((item, i) => {
      const previousControl = i > 0 ? inputs.controls[i - 1] : null;      
      inputs.push(this.fb.control(
        item.value,
        this.validator(),
        this.asyncValidator(),
      ));
    });    
  }

  private validator(previousControl: AbstractControl): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      if (!previousControl || control.value.length > previousControl.value.length) {
        return null;
      }

      return {
        notLargeEnough: 'should be bigger'
      };
    }
  }
```

You have to handle the fact that the first control doesn't have a previous control to compare against.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9atrvn

You will probably want to add something that updates the validation on the related control when a value changes, as this doesn't happen by default.

EDIT

If your array changes during its lifetime, you can use `FormControl.setValidators(validators)` to update the validators for the affected items.

If you start off with the array

`A <- B <- C <- D <- E`

And remove one:

`A <- B <- D <- E`

Then the only dependency that has changed is `D -> C` now becomes `D -> B`. So you need to update the validator for `D` to depend on `B`.

Note: using setValidators will overwrite all existing validators. So if you are using additional validators, they will also need to be included.

Forked demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f93sgn

Comment: What will happen if I add/remove controls during runtime?

Comment: Aside from managing the form array in the same way as your model, you will need to modify the affected controls at the affected indexes. I have forked my stackblitz to show how I would delete individual items. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f93sgn

Comment: Note: using `setValidators` will overwrite all existing validators. So if you are using additional validators, they will also need to be included

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a little bit more detail

Answer (score 1):

just add and arguments to the function Validator

```
private validator(indexInArray:number): ValidatorFn { //<--here
    return (abstractControl: AbstractControl) => {
      //you can use indexInArray here
     if (indexInArray==0)  //For the first give always valid
         return null; 
      //I change this.items by this.form.value
      const lenOfPrev = this.form.value[indexInArray - 1].value.length
      if (abstractControl.value.length <= lenOfPrev.length) {
        return {
          notLargeEnough: 'should be bigger'
        }
      }
      return null
    }
  }
```

But, if you're using values of the component you need "bind" the validator

```
this.items.forEach((item, i) => {
      const previousControl = i > 0 ? inputs.controls[i - 1] : null;      
      inputs.push(this.fb.control(
        item.value,
        this.validator(i).bind(this), //<--see the argument and the "bind"
        this.asyncValidator(),
      ));
    });
```

But, sorry. This aproach has a relevant faul, What happens if you change,e.g. the 2nd input from 'aaa' to 'aaaaa'?. If your 3rt input is 'bbbb', before was valid, but not after the change . But angualr can has take accont of this because the 3rt input not change. So, Why not use a Validator over all the formArray. As a custom validator return an object, you can return, e.g. an array [false,false,true,false] and ask about this value

```
  private validatorArray()
  {
    return (formArray:FormArray)=>{
      if (!formArray.value)
        return null;
      const result= (formArray.value.map((x:any,i:number)=>{
        if (i==0)
           return false;
        return (x.length<=formArray.value[i-1].length)
      }))
      return result.find(x=>x)?{error:result}:null;
    }
  }
```

In `form.errors?.error[i]` you has if a control is invalid

You can see the two aproach in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2r4czy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: I use directly a formArray of FormControls, but it's the same

**Upate** after read the answer of Kurt, really it's not necesary **bind(this)** in the validator, simple pass the previous control as Kurt say.

Comment: It is actually an interesting idea of binding validator to FormArray, and then setting validity of children